# Is it possible to access the "localhost:8080/app.html" Apache tomcat from other network?

Tags: tomcat, webserver, html

I am using a tomcat server for my webpage. I was able to access this from different computer but same network easily but is it possible in anyway to access this webpage/localhost from different network?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to be accessible outside the local network:

- Tomcat has to be configured to respond to a publicly routed IP address
- Your firewall needs to be configured to allow traffic to port 8080 (in your example) on that public IP address

or alternatively

- Use port forwarding to forward a publicly routed IP address to a private IP address that Tomcat is configured to listen on.
- Ensure that your firewall allows that connection on port 8080.

Comment: How can I configure or what should I do in tomcat?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information about your environment present to explain how to configure Tomcat in your environment.  Start by figuring out if the computer running Tomcat has a public IP address.

Comment: This is my personal computer, i don't know if it has any public ip, does it?

Comment: If you can use it to browse the web, it has a public IP.  Browse to https://www.whatismyip.com/ to see your IP address.  Open your firewall to allow inbound connections to port 8080 (and only that port, don't disable the firewall even for a moment).  Try to access Tomcat using the public IP that you discover in the previous step from outside your personal/home network.